# $(":focus") returns no element for <input type="file" /> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firefox, file-upload

I can't seem to get the currently focused/active element as a jQuery object *in Firefox*, if it is an `<input type="file" />`. It works on other input types (text, password, submit, others) and on other element types (`<select>`, `<textarea>`, others).

### HTML

```html
<input type="file" />
```

### Javascript

```js
// Cannot find input type file elements with :focus,
// $focused.length is always 0 in Firefox (tested using FF 10.0.1)
var $focusedTest1 = $(':focus');

// This line throws for Firefox (tested using FF 10.0.1)
// Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'
// @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js:108
// in jQuery.fn.init, below "Handle $(DOMElement)"
var $focusedTest2 = $(document.activeElement);
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. Use Firefox.
2. Focus the file box:

   - press tab until you reach it
   - or click in it.
3. While focusing the file box, try to get a result from `$(':focus')`.

See [jsFiddle demonstration of getting the id of the focused element](http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/bzsv7/) - test it with Firefox.

**Does anyone have a solution for getting the focused/active element as a jQuery object that works for `<input type="file" />`?**

The solution needs to be fully generic as the functionality is part of a plugin. I will not have control over the page the script will run on.

Comment: I have found something that works (in the test case at least), but it involves document level listeners and try-catch logic. Will post it in a little while.

Comment: hmm, the document.activeElement seems to yield a textfield with no id, that seems to be the problem.
And somehow it's just a different kind of element, can't do much with it.

Comment: @Johan: It might be an [XrayWrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers), which I suspect is part of the problem. *"Wrappers can appear in the console log; for example "[object XrayWrapper [object blah]]". Because these are wrapped, you won't be able to peek down inside them from the console."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** This solution has been implemented where [the problem was first found](https://github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab/issues/2), in [EmulateTab](http://joelpurra.github.com/emulatetab). See [getFocusedElement()](https://github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab/blob/master/src/emulatetab.joelpurra.js#L97).

---

Found a solution myself, after a break from coding - but it is not a very *clean* solution. It is basically the [same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301634/907779) suggested by [@Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182705/neil) while I first wrote this post.

Try [the updated jsFiddle version with focus listeners and try-catch logic](http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/bzsv7/2/) in Firefox. It combines `:focus`, `document.activeElement` and document level focus listeners that keep track of the last "known" focused element.

### Function to find focused element

```
// Comined function to get the focused element trying as long as possible.
// Extra work done trying to avoid problems with security features around
// <input type="file" /> in Firefox (tested using 10.0.1).
function getFocused() {
    // Try the well-known, recommended method first.
    var $focused = $(':focus');

    if ($focused.size() === 0) {
        try {
            // Fall back to a fast method that might fail.
            // Known to fail for Firefox (tested using 10.0.1) with
            // Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'.
            $focused = $(document.activeElement)
        }
        catch (error1) {
                warnToConsole("Could not use document.activeElement", document.activeElement, error1);

            if (lastFocusedElement !== null) {
                try {
                    // As a last resort, use the last known focused element.
                    // Has not been tested enough to be sure it works as expected.
                    $focused = $(lastFocusedElement);
                } catch (error3) {
                    warnToConsole("Could not use lastFocusedElement ", lastFocusedElement, error3);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $focused;
}
```

### Focus listeners

```
// Keep a reference to the last focused element, use as a last resort.
var lastFocusedElement = null;

function focusInElement(event) {
    lastFocusedElement = event.target;
}

function focusOutElement(event) {
    lastFocusedElement = null;
}

// Start listeners.
$(function() {
    // Start listeners that keep track of the last focused element.
    $(document).on("focusin", focusInElement);
    $(document).on("focusout", focusOutElement);
});
```

I don't like this solution very much, as it is far from as clean as just a one-line `$(':focus')`. Other answers are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to add a capturing focus listener at the window level in which you update a global variable with the event target. (In Firefox, the event target for a focus event in a file input is the file input itself even though document.activeElement returns the "anonymous" button.)

Comment: Had a break and though of a solution like that. Implemented it a little while ago - have a look at the updated code and let me know if it works!

Comment: @Joel I'm not used to focusin/focusout but it worked for me locally with a plain old focus event handler.

Comment: It [depends on the browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) if it works (bubbles); [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/)/[focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) are the normalized bubbling versions of [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)/[blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). So, best use the bubbling versions right away.

Comment: @Joel Ah, but unfortunately they're not actually implemented on Firefox yet; see [bug 687787](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787). The page could also confuse a bubbling handler by cancelling the propagation...

Comment: One of the many reasons to use jQuery is all browser normalization done in the background. See [jQuery 1.7.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) line #3649, *Create "bubbling" focus and blur events*. I think jQuery assumes that [no  browser supports focusin/focusout](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html#t06), but has prepared for a future browser support check. In either case, *jQuery* supports focusin/focusout =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this - tested in Firefox 10.0.1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var crtFocus;
        $("#id1").focus(function () {
            crtFocus = $(this);
        });
        $("#id2").focus(function () {
            crtFocus = $(this);
        });
        $("#id3").focus(function () {
            crtFocus = $(this);
        });

        $("#click").click(function () {
            // $(crtFocus) contains the currently focused element
            //alert($(crtFocus));
        });
    });


...



<input type="file" id="id1" />
<input type="file" id="id2" />
<input type="file" id="id3" />    
<input type="button" id="click"/>
```

EDIT - we can use only one selector for all input[type=file] elements instead of one selector per element

```
$(':input[type=file]').focus(function () {
            crtFocus = $(this);
        });
```

Comment: This is similar to [the implemented listener solution](http://jsfiddle.net/joelpurra/bzsv7/2/), but with one listener per file input. Since I don't know what elements may be added/removed on the page (it's a plugin), I prefer to use a fixed number (well, two) of document/window/body level listeners. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: See my edited response for the simplified version with just one selector for all file elements

Comment: Better, but won't work when the developer adds more file inputs dynamically, like gmail's "add attachment". `.live("focus", ...)` would work better.

Comment: `$('input[type=file]').live("focus", focusInElement).live("blur", focusOutElement);` seems to work. Thanks!